# A single XSL to rule them all

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm building a single XSL stylesheet to convert a number of XML files (each with a different root) to a set of divs for styling but I'm having problems with any template defined after the first, I know I'm doing something dumb/fundamentally wrong but I can't figure out what it is, so any advice would be appreciated.

I'm fairly sure this has asked before but after a few hours of searching I cannot find a result.

XML#1:

```
<domain:create xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" xmlns:domain="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0 domain-1.0.xsd">
  <domain:name>exampledomain.gtld</domain:name>
  <domain:period unit="y">1</domain:period>
  <domain:ns>
    <domain:hostAttr>
      <domain:hostName>ns1.exampledomain.gtld</domain:hostName>
      <domain:hostAddr ip="v4">x.x.x.x</domain:hostAddr> 
      <domain:hostAddr ip="v4">y.y.y.y</domain:hostAddr> 
      <domain:hostAddr ip="v6">ff02::1</domain:hostAddr> 
    </domain:hostAttr>
    <domain:hostAttr>
      <domain:hostName>ns1.otherdomain.gtld</domain:hostName> 
    </domain:hostAttr>
  </domain:ns>
  <domain:registrant>RegistrantID</domain:registrant>
  <domain:contact type="admin">AdminID</domain:contact>
  <domain:contact type="tech">TechID</domain:contact>
  <domain:contact type="billing">BillingID</domain:contact>
  <domain:contact type="reseller">ResellerID</domain:contact>
  <domain:authInfo>
    <domain:pw>TransferPassword</domain:pw>
  </domain:authInfo>
</domain:create>
```

XML#2

```
<domain:update xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:epp-1.0" xmlns:domain="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0 domain-1.0.xsd">
  <domain:name>exampledomain.gtld</domain:name>
  <domain:add>
    <domain:ns>
      <domain:hostAttr>
        <domain:hostName>ns1.exampledomain.gtld</domain:hostName>
        <domain:hostAddr ip="v4">1.1.1.1</domain:hostAddr>
      </domain:hostAttr>
    </domain:ns>
    <domain:contact type="tech">NewTechID</domain:contact>
    <domain:status s="clientHold">Payment overdue.</domain:status>
  </domain:add>
  <domain:rem>
    <domain:ns>
      <domain:hostAttr>
        <domain:hostName>ns1.otherdomain.gtld</domain:hostName>
      </domain:hostAttr>
    </domain:ns>
    <domain:status s="clientTransferProhibited"/>
  </domain:rem>
  <domain:chg>          
    <domain:registrant>NewRegistrantID</domain:registrant>
    <domain:authInfo>
      <domain:pw>NewPassword</domain:pw>
    </domain:authInfo>
  </domain:chg>
</domain:update>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:domain="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:domain-1.0">

<xsl:variable name="vLower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>

<xsl:variable name="vUpper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="domain:update">
  <div class="action">Domain Update: '<xsl:value-of select="domain:name"/>'</div>
    <div class="attributes">
      <xsl:for-each select="domain:ns/domain:hostAttr">
        <div class="hostname">Nameserver: <xsl:value-of select="domain:hostName"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="domain:hostAddr">
            <div>
              <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="@ip"/>_address</xsl:attribute>
              IP<xsl:value-of select="@ip"/> Glue: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </div>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </div>  
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
    <div class="contacts">
      <div class="contact_registrant">Registrant: <xsl:value-of select="domain:registrant"/></div>
      <xsl:for-each select="domain:contact">
        <div>  
          <xsl:attribute name="class">contact_<xsl:value-of select="@type"/></xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring(@type,1,1), $vLower, $vUpper), substring(@type, 2), substring('', 1 div not(position()=last())))"/>: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
    <div class="password">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="domain:create">
  <div class="action">Domain Create: '<xsl:value-of select="domain:name"/>' for a period of <xsl:value-of select="domain:period"/> <xsl:value-of select="domain:period/@unit"/></div>
    <div class="attributes">
      <xsl:for-each select="domain:ns/domain:hostAttr">
        <div class="hostname">Nameserver: <xsl:value-of select="domain:hostName"/>
          <xsl:for-each select="domain:hostAddr">
            <div>
              <xsl:attribute name="class"><xsl:value-of select="@ip"/>_address</xsl:attribute>
              IP<xsl:value-of select="@ip"/> Glue: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </div>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </div>  
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
    <div class="contacts">
      <div class="contact_registrant">Registrant: <xsl:value-of select="domain:registrant"/></div>
      <xsl:for-each select="domain:contact">
        <div>
          <xsl:attribute name="class">contact_<xsl:value-of select="@type"/></xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring(@type,1,1), $vLower, $vUpper), substring(@type, 2), substring('', 1 div not(position()=last())))"/>: <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </div>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
    <div class="password">
</xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using XML#1 produces:

```
exampledomain.gtld 1 ns1.exampledomain.gtld x.x.x.x y.y.y.y ff02::1 ns1.otherdomain.gtld RegistrantID AdminID TechID BillingID ResellerID TransferPassword
```

But using XML#2 produces (as expected):

```
Domain Update: 'exampledomain.gtld'
Registrant:
```

If I **swap** the named templates then it works.

**STUPIDITY UPDATE**
I omitted the closing `</div>` tags for `<div class="Password">`

Comment: I adjusted the template selector which returns the correct name()

Comment: I'm using http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog to test the XSL translation

Comment: I built the XSL from ground up and got it working on `<xsl:template match="/domain:create">` before I tried introducing the `/domain:update` code.

Comment: Incorporated suggestions from michael.hor257k and michael-kay for a more concise question

Comment: Found the issue: I was missing a *&^#ing closing div tag on password which was causing the issues.

Comment: Your stupidity was not in omitting the closing tag, we all do that kind of thing. Your mistake was in how you approached solving the problem. My mistake too: I should have learned by now never to accept "it doesn't work" as a sufficient description of a problem. But the fact that you had no clue that the stylesheet was ill-formed means you aren't using the right development tools: and that's the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lost you at this point:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="name() = 'domain:update'">
      <xsl:call-template name="domain_update"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise test="name() = 'domain:create'">
      <xsl:call-template name="domain_create"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

You are in the context of the root node`/`. This node has no name, so the test for:

```
<xsl:when test="name() = 'domain:update'">
```

will **never** return true. Perhaps you should try with:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
```

instead.

The other thing is that `<xsl:otherwise>` cannot have a `test` attribute. If you want to perform another test, you need to use another `<xsl:when>` tag. Use `<xsl:otherwise>` to specify the *default* result in case all the tests have returned false.

Note also that instead of this verbose branching, you could simply have a template that matches `domain:create` and another that matches `domain:update`. Then a simple:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

would do the job for you. And you don't even have to write this in your stylesheet, because the built-in template rules will do just that.

---

**Important:**

I did not go into the contents of your named templates, but I suspect they need a thorough revision too. But that would be too much for one question.

Comment: Got you on the otherwise, thanks. Also tried `template match="/"` with the other templates match on `domain:update` and `domain:create` but it doesn't work

Comment: @McAnix "doesn't work" is not a good description of a problem.

Comment: If I switch the declaration order of `<xsl:template match="domain:create">` and `domain:update` then your suggestion provides output if I use XML#1 but not if I use XML#2 and vice versa

Comment: Here's an example of a skeleton template being applied to your XML #1 document: http://xsltransform.net/bdxtqd Here's the **same** template being applied to your XML #2: http://xsltransform.net/bdxtqd/1

Comment: **NOTE** There's an issue with how your documents declare the domain namespace; but that's (yet) another story...

Comment: I'm accepting yours as the answer because you directed me to an intelligent tool xsltransform.net which revealed the REAL problem... Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

"/" refers to the document node, which is the parent of the outermost element node. The document node is unnamed, so name() returns an empty string, so the test "name() = 'domain:update'" fails, and you always fall into the "otherwise" branch.

It's a poor test anyway. By doing a string comparison on the result of the name() function, you're matching only if the source document uses this particular namespace prefix. You shouldn't care what prefix is used.

It would be much better to use XSLT the way it is designed to be used, with matching template rules. Like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="domain:update">
  ...
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="domain:create">
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Tried this, no joy, it returns the XML as parsed HTML

Comment: ... also I will be parsing other namespace prefixes such as `contact:create`

Comment: Isn't "parsed HTML" what you are trying to produce?